# DHL trackShipmentRequest - WDSL - PHP - SOAP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

First post so forgive any breach of forum rules etc.
I am trying to use the DHL api to track shipments.

Here is the code i have currently

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://wsbuat.dhl.com:8300/gbl/glDHLExpressTrack?wsdl");
    //$header     = new SoapHeader("https://wsbuat.dhl.com:8300/gbl/glDHLExpressTrack?wsdl", "APICredentials", $auth, false); 
    //$client->__setLocation('https://wsbuat.dhl.com:8300/gbl/glDHLExpressTrack?wsdl');

    $header_part = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:rat="https://wsbuat.dhl.com:8300/gbl/glDHLExpressTrack?wsdl"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-
    secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-5" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-
    wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:Username>myusername</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-
    1.0#PasswordText">mypassword</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-
    1.0#Base64Binary">eUYebYfsjztETJ4Urt8AJw==</wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created>2010-02-12T17:40:39.124Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>';




$soap_var_header = new SoapVar( $header_part, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null );
$soap_header = new SoapHeader( 'https://wsbuat.dhl.com:8300/gbl/glDHLExpressTrack', 'wsse', $soap_var_header, true );
$client->__setSoapHeaders($soap_header);
```

If i do

var_dump($client->__getFunctions())

I get the following:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(83) "trackShipmentRequestResponse trackShipmentRequest(trackShipmentRequest $parameters)" }
```

My question really is does anyone know how to then format the trackShipmentRequest

```
$client->trackShipmentRequest(what goes here);
```

Here is an example of the xml given to me by DHL to be used in soapui

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:trac="http://scxgxtt.phx-dc.dhl.com/glDHLExpressTrack/providers/services/trackShipment" xmlns:dhl="http://www.dhl.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <trac:trackShipmentRequest>
         <trackingRequest>
            <dhl:TrackingRequest>
               <Request>
                  <ServiceHeader>
                     <MessageTime>2013-05-13T10:17:20Z</MessageTime>
                     <MessageReference>c68d7150bbd611e2b09ad103c98eed12</MessageReference>
                  </ServiceHeader>
               </Request>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <AWBNumber>
                  <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
                  <ArrayOfAWBNumberItem>2786552086</ArrayOfAWBNumberItem>
               </AWBNumber>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <LPNumber>
                  <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
                  <ArrayOfTrackingPieceIDItem>?</ArrayOfTrackingPieceIDItem>
               </LPNumber>
               <LevelOfDetails>ALL_CHECK_POINTS</LevelOfDetails>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <PiecesEnabled>B</PiecesEnabled>
            </dhl:TrackingRequest>
         </trackingRequest>
      </trac:trackShipmentRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>

    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I realise there a similar topics on this site, but none seem to help.

Comment: I think DHL's SOAP API has been discontinued. I was unable to get the any XML output from `wsbuat.dhl.com`. I think you're better off with [DHL XML Services](http://www.dhl.com/en/express/resource_center/integrated_shipping_solutions.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WSDL endpoint you are using in your first line

```
new SoapClient("https://wsbuat.dhl.com:8300/gbl/glDHLExpressTrack?wsdl");
```

isn't even resolving. I don't think it will work. Usually if you just paste https://wsbuat.dhl.com:8300/gbl/glDHLExpressTrack?wsdl in your browser you should be able to see definition for most SOAP services from what I know.

Based on user555 comment, the endpoint may have been deprecated so you should contact DHL.

Comment: I think this question has been open long enough. I believe as I am in Spain DHL are supplying an old deprecated service that they have little to no good documentation on. I believe what you say is probably correct. Anyway been a while, but I am clearing old questions.