# How to consume a DHL API (Germany)

Tags: php, xml, curl, dhl

I am trying to track a shipment to get the status and date of it. For that I was checking the DHL documentation from the site in Germany, but is not really good to be honest.

Anyways, there's a testsuite which I downloaded and read, and there they say:

> If you are working with the GET method, you can also view the link,
>   all necessary information is contained in the URL.
>
> Here you will find the complete URL as the first entry:
>
> GET
>   https://cig.dhl.de/services/sandbox/rest/sendungsverfolgung?xml=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20standalone%3D%22no%22%3F%3E%20%3Cdata%20appname%3D%22zt12345%22%20language-code%3D%22de%22%20password%3D%22geheim%22%20piece-code%3D%2200340434161094015902%22%20request%3D%22d-get-piece-detail%22%2F%3E%20
>   HTTP/1.1
>
> You can also put this link into your browser. **(doing that doesn't work for me)**
>   That link supposed to output in XML format.

So my question is...How can I get the info from that URL in PHP? to then be able to retrieve the specific info in it.

Comment: To me, the "link" looks like as it is already url-encoded, what most browsers would do again for the input url. You would have to replace all `%xx` by the de-hexacedimalized character eg `%20`->space

Comment: if the information is contained in the URL, you can `parse_str` (php) the url, and `url_decode` (php) the xml parameter in the query part. what you'll get is a ..... string probably? wrapped in some xml-nonsense. so you could run it through an xml parser and what not ... sounds like an awful lot of work ^^

Comment: so, what is after the `?xml=` is the following: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> <data appname="zt12345" language-code="de" password="geheim" piece-code="00340434161094015902" request="d-get-piece-detail"/>` I don't know what kind of information you're looking for though ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way will be to use this library which implements the DHL API methods quite well:
https://github.com/alfallouji/DHL-API

You might also refer to this post where they discuss different ways of using the API:
[DHL Tracking Api and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902983/dhl-tracking-api-and-php)